# Different naming artifacts on appveyor when tag pushed?

Tags: appveyor

I have this pattern in appveyor.yml:

```
  - path: Foo\bin\$(configuration)
    name: Foo_%APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION%
    type: zip
```

When i push some regular commit, i get artifact `Foo_123_master.zip`.

Want `Foo_1.4.8.zip`, when push release tag `1.4.8`.

Appveyor have `%APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME%` environment variable, but how to setup artifacts to different naming on regular build and tag pushed build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce another environment variable and set it depending on the build type, for example:

```
init:
- ps: |
    $env:artifact_suffix = $env:APPVEYOR_BUILD_VERSION
    if ($env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG -eq 'true') {
      $env:artifact_suffix = $env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME
    }
```

and then in `artifacts` section:

```
  - path: Foo\bin\$(configuration)
    name: Foo_%artifact_suffix%
    type: zip
```